# how i get connection type like wifi, Ethernet or cellular in javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

im looking for network connection type like wifi, celular etc. im found sintax
`navigator.connection`

result:

```
downlink: 10
effectiveType: "4g"
onchange: null
rtt: 150
saveData: false
```

effectiveType not detect my connection type is wifi

Answer (score 1):

The type of the network connection is, by the spec, accessible via [`navigator.connection.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation#properties). However this is not yet implemented in almost all browsers at the time of writing except for Chrome on Chrome OS.

The `effectiveType` property is simply a deduced value based on the network speed and does not tell you of the actual connection itself.

Comment: Thank you. so, am I not able to get my connection type?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is still an experimental feature. So you can't expect that it works reliable yet.

Besides that:

[NetworkInformation.effectiveType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation)

> Returns the effective type of the connection meaning one of 'slow-2g', '2g', '3g', or '4g'. This value is determined using a combination of recently observed round-trip time and downlink values.

There is no `wifi` for `effectiveType`, that information is in `type`.

`effectiveType` should give you an idea about how fast the connection is.

Comment: thank you for your information. do you know how i can get my connection type?